# Dictionary/word count of the number of times a word is used in a .txt file

Tags: python, dictionary

This is the code I have so far. I am wanting to print a dictionary/word count of the number of times a word is used in a .txt file. But I am having a problem with words popping up that aren't English.

```
    dropChars = "*!@#$%ˆ&()½_+-={}[]|\\:;\"’<>,.?/1234567890"
    dropDict = dict([(c, ' ') for c in dropChars])
    dropTable = str.maketrans(dropDict)

    with open(input("Paste file path here: "), 'r') as file:

    wordNum = 0;
    table = {}  # dictionary: words -> set of line numbers
    for line in file:
    words = line.upper().translate(dropTable).split()

    for word in words:
        wordNum += 1
        if word in table:
            table[word] = table[word] + 1
        else:
            table[word] = 1

        sorted_table = (sorted(table.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True))


        for (k,v) in sorted_table:

        print(str(k) + " :   " + str(v))
```

Comment: Do you want to ignore if the text is not English?

Comment: "But I am having a problem with words popping up that aren't English". Understood. It turns out the vast majority of possible 'words' are not English. What is your question? What do you want to do? Please do not say "Plz help". Of course you need help, or you wouldn't be asking the question...

Comment: Hapaxes (unique tokens) are a natural and unavoidable feature of natural text. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: I'd be tempted to use a regular expression to exclude everything that isn't a character of interest, e.g. `re.sub(r'[^A-Z]+', ' ', line)`

Comment: @MayankPorwal Yes, I would like to print a table of all the English words. Ignoring all the non-English words that appear in the table

Comment: @MattMessersmith I am currently reading a .txt file and it takes of of the words from the file. But if it takes an email address it will sore the word as e.g "GMAILCOM" as this word isn't english I don't want it to be added to the table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, this doesn't work when I believe it should...

```
 dropChars = "*!@#$%ˆ&()½_+-={}[]|\\:;\"’<>,.?/1234567890"
 dropDict = dict([(c, ' ') for c in dropChars])
 dropTable = str.maketrans(dropDict)

 english_words = open("/Users/MaxEllis/Desktop/Griffith/Repo/english_words.txt", "r+")
 e_words = set(word.strip().lower() for word in english_words)


 def is_english_word(word):
     return word.lower() in e_words


 with open(input("Paste file path here: "), 'r') as file:
    # Make a translation table for getting rid of non-word  characters
    wordNum = 0;
    table = {}  # dictionary: words -> set of line numbers
    for line in file:
    words = line.upper().translate(dropTable).split()

    for word in words:
        wordNum += 1
        if word in table:
            table[word] = table[word] + 1
        else:
            table[word] = 1

 sorted_table = (sorted(table.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True))

 for (k, v) in sorted_table:
     print(str(k) + " :   " + str(v))

 english_words.close()
```